# How to avoid duplicate content file_put_contents when creating a command in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a command in laravel, where I copy my views correctly to the views folder, but it happens that I want to add some routes and I do it in the following way

```
file_put_contents(
       base_path('routes/web.php'),
       file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/stubs/make/routes.stub'),
       FILE_APPEND
);
```

I add the routes correctly but this is done every time I use the command php artisan make: micommand, is there any way to evaluate that if the routes already exist do not add them?

**Use Laravel 5.6.***

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson the version is 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in way to check for this issue. But one idea I have would be to put a very distinct comment into the `routes/web.php` (e.g. as part of the stub) for which you can check afterwards.

`stubs/make/routes.stub`:

```
// my.pkg.routes.web
Route::group([], function () {
    Route::resource('something');
});
```

Command:

```
$routes = file_get_contents(base_path('routes/web.php'));
if(strpos($routes, '\/\/ my.pkg.routes.web') === false) {
    file_put_contents(
        base_path('routes/web.php'),
        file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/stubs/make/routes.stub'),
        FILE_APPEND
    );
}
```

You could also make the comment a constant in the command  class and append it from there (would probably make more sense).

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a name to one of your routes and check it during the command via the `Route::has` method.

Assign name:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    dd('Testing route');
})->name('test');
```

Check the route inside the command:

```
if (!Route::has('test')) {
    <append your routes via stub>
})
```